# How can I create a z3c.form that has multiple schemas?

Tags: python, plone, zope, z3c.form

I am using the cms Plone to build a form that contains two other schemas.

With the [Group Forms](https://pythonhosted.org/z3c.form/group.html), I have been able to include both of the fields of the two schemas. However, they lose all of their properties such as hidden or when I use datagridfield to build the table. What I want to be able to do is have both of these forms with their fields and on a save be able to save them in the object which the link was clicked as parent -> object 1 [top of the form] -> object 2 [bottom of the form]

Here is my python code:

```
class QuestionPart(group.Group):
    label = u'Question Part'
    fields = field.Fields(IQuestionPart)
    template = ViewPageTemplateFile('questionpart_templates/view.pt')

 class Question(group.Group):
     label = u'Question'
     fields = field.Fields(IQuestion)
     template = ViewPageTemplateFile('question_templates/view.pt')

class QuestionSinglePart(group.GroupForm, form.AddForm):
    grok.name('register')
    grok.require('zope2.View')
    grok.context(ISiteRoot)
    label = u"Question with Single Part"

    ignoreContext = True
    enable_form_tabbing  = False

    groups = (Question,QuestionPart)

def update(self):
    super(QuestionSinglePart, self).update()
```

This code displays both the fields of IQuestion, IQuestionPart without the regard to things like: form.mode(contype='hidden') or DataGridField widget. 
I found a way that displays the correct form with field hints.

```
class QuestionSinglePart(AutoExtensibleForm, form.AddForm):
    grok.require('zope2.View')
    grok.context(ISiteRoot)

    label = u"Question"
    schema = IQuestion
    additionalSchemata = (IQuestionPart,)
```

I feel I am still a long way off. I have talked to some people. I am now trying to use a separate form and view.

So far, I am at this point with my code:

```
class QuestionSinglePartForm(AutoExtensibleForm, form.Form):

    ignoreContext = True

    autoGroups = True
    template = ViewPageTemplateFile('questionsinglepart_templates/questionsinglepartform.pt')

    @property
    def additionalSchemata(self):
        return self._additionalSchemata

    def __init__(self, context, request, schema, additional=()):
        self.context = context
        self.request = request
        if not IInterface.providedBy(schema):
            raise ValueError('Schema is not interface object')
        self._schema = schema
        if not all(IInterface.providedBy(s) for s in additional):
            raise ValueError('Additional schema is not interface')
        self._additionalSchemata = additional

class QuestionSinglePartView(object):

    schema = IQuestion
    additional = (IQuestionPart,)

    def __init__(self, context, request):
        self.context = context
        self.request = request
        self.form = QuestionSinglePartForm(context, request, self.schema, self.additional)

    def magic(self, data, errors):
        pass
        """
        question = Question()
        question.number = data['number']
        question.questionContent = data['questionContent']

        questionPart = QuestionPart()
        questionPart.typeOfQuestion = data['IQuestionPart.typeOfQuestion']
        questionPart.explanation = data['IQuestionPart.explanation'] 
        questionPart.fileSize = data['IQuestionPart.fileSize']
        questionPart.fileType = data['IQuestionPart.fileType']
        questionPart.hints = data['IQuestionPart.hints']
        questionPart.table = data['IQuestionPart.table']
        questionPart.contype = data['IQuestionPart.contype']
        questionPart.content = data['IQuestionPart.content']
        """

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.get('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST':
            data, errors = self.form.extractData()
            self.magic(data, errors)
        self.formdisplay = self.form.render()

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.update(*args, **kwargs)
        return self.index(*args, **kwargs)
```

I am struggling with the rendering of the form and that the QuestionSinglePart object does not have an index attribute.

After a couple of hours of working with some plone devs, we have figured out what was going on.

I had left out:

```
    @property
    def schema(self):
        return self._schema
```

I needed to define an index in the view like so:

```
index = ViewPageTemplateFile('questionsinglepart_templates/questionsinglepart.pt')
```

I needed to add this to the views **init**:

```
alsoProvides(self.form, IWrappedForm)
```

In the update method for view I needed to call this before the formdisplay. I could also remove the data extraction and move that to the form.

```
def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.form.update(*args, **kwargs)
    self.formdisplay = self.form.render()
```

I am still currently working to get the data to save into objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my final code with the changes made above. There were issues with the index for the object. I needed to create a simple custom view. I forgot the property for schema on the form. I need to changed my update method for the view as well.

```
class QuestionSinglePartForm(AutoExtensibleForm, form.Form):

    ignoreContext = True

    autoGroups = False

    @property
    def schema(self):
        return self._schema

    @property
    def additionalSchemata(self):
        return self._additionalSchemata

    def __init__(self, context, request, schema, additional=()):
        self.context = context
        self.request = request
        if not IInterface.providedBy(schema):
            raise ValueError('Schema is not interface object')
        self._schema = schema
        if not all(IInterface.providedBy(s) for s in additional):
            raise ValueError('Additional schema is not interface')
        self._additionalSchemata = additional

    @button.buttonAndHandler(u'Save')
    def handleSave(self, action):
        data, errors = self.extractData()
        if errors:
            return False
        obj = self.createAndAdd(data)
        if obj is not None:
            # mark only as finished if we get the new object
            self._finishedAdd = True
            IStatusMessage(self.request).addStatusMessage(_(u"Changes saved"), "info")
        print data

    @button.buttonAndHandler(u'Cancel')
    def handleCancel(self, action):
        print 'cancel'



class QuestionSinglePartView(object):

    schema = IQuestion
    additional = (IQuestionPart,)
    index = ViewPageTemplateFile('questionsinglepart_templates/questionsinglepart.pt')

    def __init__(self, context, request):
        self.context = context
        self.request = request
        self.form = QuestionSinglePartForm(context, request, self.schema, self.additional)
        alsoProvides(self.form, IWrappedForm)

    def magic(self, data, errors):
        pass
        """
        question = Question()
        question.number = data['number']
        question.questionContent = data['questionContent']

        questionPart = QuestionPart()
        questionPart.typeOfQuestion = data['IQuestionPart.typeOfQuestion']
        questionPart.explanation = data['IQuestionPart.explanation'] 
        questionPart.fileSize = data['IQuestionPart.fileSize']
        questionPart.fileType = data['IQuestionPart.fileType']
        questionPart.hints = data['IQuestionPart.hints']
        questionPart.table = data['IQuestionPart.table']
        questionPart.contype = data['IQuestionPart.contype']
        questionPart.content = data['IQuestionPart.content']
        """

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.form.update(*args, **kwargs)
        self.formdisplay = self.form.render()

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.update(*args, **kwargs)
        return self.index(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Only form classes that include the `plone.autoform.base.AutoExtensibleForm` mixin pay attention to schema form hints. Try using this as a mixin to your Group form class (and provide the `schema` attribute that this mixin looks for instead of `fields`):

```
from plone.autoform.base import AutoExtensibleForm

class QuestionPart(AutoExtensibleForm, group.Group):
    label = u'Question Part'
    schema = IQuestionPart
    template = ViewPageTemplateFile('questionpart_templates/view.pt')
```

Comment: Thank you David. When importing from plone.autoform.base, I would get a import error "ImportError: cannot import name AutoExtensibleForm". However, when I change base to form it works. Except, I get an error message saying Question does not have the attribute updateActions.